# Vector of 12 elements in a rectangular block on a flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, vector

Recently i started to study Latex, tikZ and PGF. Tell me how to fit a vector of 12 elements into a rectangular block on a block diagram for a program?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It is not very clear what you like to do. Please show us what you try so far or at least add an sketch to your question which will illustrate your problem.

Comment: A 12-dimensional vector in a 3D box?

Comment: I want to do something like this:

[link]http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/PNG/simple-flow-chart.png

But, in these blocks (instead of text) I need to insert mathematical expressions, vectors and matrices.
How to do it?

[link]https://ibb.co/RTBKXzY

Comment: Please pprovide what you try so far. At least write some equation which you like to have in some node. In general the following should work: `\node {$c^2 = a^2+b^2$};

Comment: How can i put plot (for example, quadratic function), into the block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome, i guess you should just use math mode ($some text$).
Also if you want to use matrices you may need to use the package amsmath. I see you are new to Latex and Tikz so maybe you should get yourself a manual. Everything you want you can just search up in the Tikz/PGF manual or the LaTeX documentation. But here is an example (untested) anyway:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw (0,0) node[minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm, draw] (node1) {$1 \times 1 + 1 - 1 \div 1 = 1$}
                (0,-3) node[minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm, draw, circle] (node2) {$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 6 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$};
          \draw[<->] (node1) -- (node2);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see matrices can be inserted into nodes by using:

```
$\begin{matrix} 2 & 4 \\ 6 & 0 \end{matrix}$
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. This language is very difficult for a beginner to understand.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I still have questions, I will ask them.

Comment: How can i put plot (for example, quadratic function), into the block?